# Azure Data Factory Trigger

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have an external source which will copy a file on to our Azure File Server. The size of the file is around 10 GB. I want to copy this file to Azure Blob Storage as soon as the file copy is complete on Azure file server using Azure Data Factory.
The vendor cannot copy this file to Blob container.
Can someone help me what type of trigger i can configure for this. I was able to do the copy manually but i am looking if we can automate it. I cannot even schedule this activity as the file copy from external source is at random time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.. you can have a logic app triggered on an event on storage which will trigger data factory pipeline ..copy activity can do the job for you inside ADF..